# Initialize and fill array with custom object inline

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array with 10 objects all of the same self-created class.

```
let myArray = [CustomObject(), CustomObject(), CustomObject(), CustomObject(), CustomObject(), CustomObject(), CustomObject(), CustomObject(), CustomObject(), CustomObject()]
```

I wonder if there is a shortcut for creating such an array like in Python where I would do something like

```
myArray = [CustomObject() for _ in range(10)]
```

I have seen these solutions: [StackOverflow-Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232475/create-array-of-strings-using-for-in-in-swift) but they don't seem to work with not built-in classes.

```
let myArray2 = (0...9).map{CustomObject()}
```

says "Type of expression is amiguous without more context"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
let myArray = [CustomObject](repeating: CustomObject(), count: 10)
```

By using Array.init(repeating:) will invoke the CustomObject initialize only one time, and then insert that object into the array multiple times.

If you want to use Array.init(repeating:) with the different object I found one thread and extension
https://forums.swift.org/t/support-repeating-initializers-with-closures-not-just-values/14666/5

If you want to use the map and for different object.

```
let myArray2 = (0...9).map { (_) -> CustomObject in
    CustomObject()
}
```

Comment: Your solution using `Array.init(repeating:)` will invoke the CustomObject initializer only once, and then insert that object into the array multiple times. That is likely not what the OP wants or expects.

Comment: No I need 10 different objects. So the map solution would be what I need?

Comment: @DuncanC yes you are right. Using Array.init(repeating:) object initializer only one time. so a map is a good solution in my view.

Comment: If you want to use  Array.init(repeating:) with the different object I found one thread and extension
https://forums.swift.org/t/support-repeating-initializers-with-closures-not-just-values/14666/5

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing an [AnyIterator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyiterator) that produces infinite `Void`s is my recommendation. Then you don’t need to disregard a closure parameter, allowing you to use the initializer directly as a named closure.

```swift
AnyIterator { } .prefix(10).map(CustomObject.init)
```